# finding values for which a function lies between an interval

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I have a bit of elementary calculus problem for which my knowledge has become rusty.

I have the function $\left ( a-1 \right )x-ax^{3}$.
I would like to determine the values of a for which the function $f\left ( x \right ) \in \left [ -1,1 \right ]$.

To do so, I begin with determining the extrema using the stationary point:

$f'\left ( x \right )=a-1-3ax^{2}=0$

This yields the two points $x_{\pm }=\pm \left [ \frac{1}{3}\left ( 1-\frac{1}{a} \right ) \right ]^{1/2}$ for which the extrema lies. $x_{+}$ corresponds the a maxima and $x_{-}$ corresponds to a minima of the function.

How do I continue?

My text mentioned that $0\leq 1-\frac{1}{a}<3$ for which I am unable to understand how it is arrived at and the principles behind.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the range of $x$ values (for example, $0 \le x \le 1$)?

Comment: There is something missing in your set of hypotheses since for $a \ne 0$, $f(x) \to (-\operatorname{sign}(a)) \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ etc.  So I, like @martycohen, wonder if you don't need to restrict the domain of $f(x)$.

Comment: @martycohen has a good point here. Your function diverges to $\pm \infty$

Comment: @martycohen I believe it is strictly from -1 to 1. My assumption is based on the domain of the plot which is shown on the text.

Comment: Looking at the graph, it would seem that $f(x) \in [-1,1]$ for $x \in [0,1]$ when $a \in [-1/2, 4]$

Comment: That's the answer of a one would eventually arrived at. You are correct.
However, how does one arrive at $0\leq 1-\frac{1}{a}<3$. This is very important to me.@BrevanEllefsen
I do not always have access to mathematical software tools...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at first note that for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ it holds that: 
$$f(-x)=-f(x)\mbox{ and }f(0)=0$$
so, if there exists a $A>0$ such that for every $x\in[0,A]$ it holds that $|f(x)|\leq1$ for some values of $a$ then, *for exactly the same values of* $a$, it holds that $|f(x)|\leq1$ for $x\in[-A,0]$. Then, we can restrict our research to an interval of the form $[0,A]$, where $A>0$ and $A$ is independent of $a$.

Now, let us also make a crucial note:
$$f(1)=a-1-a=-1\mbox{ and }f(-1)=-1+a-a=1$$
for every $a\in\mathbb{R}$, which means that a "convenient" choice of $A$ would be:
$$A=1$$
Now, in the interval $[0,1]$, since $f$ is continuous, it attains both its maximum and its minimum. To find them, we have:
$$f'(x)=a-1-3ax^2$$
and, then:
$$f'(x)=0\overset{x\geq0}{\Leftrightarrow}x=\sqrt{\frac{a-1}{3a}}=x_0$$
which are well-defined iff $$\frac{a-1}{3a}\geq0\Leftrightarrow a< 0\mbox{ or }a\geq1$$
Now, we also need - since $x_0\in[0,1]$ - that 
$$0\leq x_0\leq1\Leftrightarrow\dots\Leftrightarrow0\leq\frac{a-1}{3a}\leq1\Leftrightarrow a\in\left[-\frac{1}{2},0\right)\cup[1,+\infty)$$
Now, calculating $f(x_0)$ we get:
$$f(x_0)=\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{\frac{(a-1)^3}{a}}$$
Since we need $|f(x_0)|\leq1$, we have:
$$\frac{(a-1)^3}{a}\leq\frac{27}{4}\Leftrightarrow\dots\Leftrightarrow a\leq4$$
(taking into consideration that $a\in\left[-\frac{1}{2},0\right)\cup[1,+\infty)$). So, finally:
$$a\in\left[-\frac{1}{2},0\right)\cup[1,4]$$
Lastly, for every $a\in[0,1)$ we shall note that
$$f'(x)\leq0$$
for every $x\in[0,1]$
so $f$ is decreasing, which means that:
$$|f(x)|\leq\max\{|f(0)|,|f(1)|\}=1$$
So, we get that:
$$a\in\left[-\frac{1}{2},4\right]$$
and $x\in[-1,1]$.